# Confusing warning about a constant decimal field in C#

Tags: c#, constants

I was experimenting with the `const` modifier while exploring a plethora of C# tutorials, and placed a bunch of `const` modifiers in a class like this without actually using them anywhere:

```
class ConstTesting
{
    const decimal somedecimal = 1;
    const int someint = 2;
    ...
}
```

With this class, I get the following warning (using csc) :

> ConstTesting.cs(3,19): warning CS0414: The field ‘ConstTesting.somedecimal’
>   is assigned but its value is never used

**What I don't understand is that** I only get the warning for the `const decimal`. The `const int` doesn't give me any warning, regardless of the order or anything like that. 

**My question is,** why does this happen? Why would my csc compiler be warning me about a `const` in the first place, and if it is then more importantly **why would it only be warning me about `const decimal`** when I'm writing `const int` in exactly the same way? What on earth would the difference between `int` and `decimal` have to do with it?

**Please note:**

  - I do not have ReSharper
  - I am using VS 2010
  - I am 100% certain neither `const` is being used anywhere in my code.

Comment: I am quite certain I am using neither anywhere actually.

Comment: I am quite certain you are! Try `public class Foo{const int bar = 2;}`, you'll see.

Comment: It is not in my code. I can take out the `...`, do literally nothing else and I still only get warned about the `const decimal`. Try it for yourself.

Comment: Try the class I just gave you, it clearly give the warning. Also, right click that `someint` and press `Find Usages`. If there's really no usage found (which would be surprising), clean up the project.

Comment: Oh, I have ReSharper on though. And your specific VS version could be useful too, just in case.

Comment: Try without it. I am only getting a warning for the `const decimal`, like I said.

Comment: @Elizion  open http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/category/csharp/ and search for "const decimal ConstDecimal = 5" maybe it helps

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Int is a simple value type of a fixed size.  Decimal is a bit more complicated due to scale.  If you decompile your code, you'll find that it looks like this:

```
[DecimalConstant(0, 0, 0, 0, 1)]
private readonly static decimal somedecimal;

private const int someint = 2;
```

Where the decimal is not a constant, but has a DecimalConstant attribute courtesy of mscorlib.dll, where the true definition if decimal is:

```
public struct Decimal : IFormattable, IComparable, IConvertible,
IDeserializationCallback, IComparable<decimal>, IEquatable<decimal>
```

Much more in-depth exploration of this topic is covered in  [this  blog post](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2014/08/).

Comment: This leads to another question whether changing value of `const decimal` is a breaking change like changing value of `const int`.

Comment: This is interesting. So you are saying, using a `const decimal` isn't actually a "real" `const`? Also, many thanks for not just telling me I'm an idiot and have used my `someint` somewhere.

Comment: That's technically correct.  The DecimalConstant attribute should enforce the behavior of a constant, but it's a bit of smoke and mirrors to keep things simple.  Your question was a bit more complicated that it looks like at first glance.  Of course the solution is to use your constants.  :)